# cloudformation to get DNSName from LoadBalancerArn

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

My load balancer already exists and was not created with cloudformation.

I pass in the full arn as a param for resources that need it like a listener:

```
  Listener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
      - Type: forward
        TargetGroupArn: !Ref MyTargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalancerARN
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
```

In this template that consumes the LoadBalacnerArn i also want it to output the DNSName of that loadbalancer- is this possible?

Doing this I can return the ARN that was passed in as a param:

```
Outputs:
  LoadBalancerName:
    Description: The DNS Name of the ALB where this container was deploy
    Value: !Ref LoadBalancerARN
```

I tried this to get the DNS name like this but I get an error:

```
Outputs:
  LoadBalancerName:
    Description: The DNS Name of the ALB where this container was deploy
    Value: !GetAtt !Ref LoadBalancerARN.DNSName
```

Is there a way to !GetAtt of a !Ref like this?

Couple other attempts:

```
Value:
  !GetAtt
    - DNSName
    - !Ref LoadBalancerARN
```

This doesn't work either

```
Value:
  !GetAtt
  - !Ref LoadBalancerARN
  - LoadBalancerARN.DNSName
```

Perhaps I could do something hacky like parse the arn to get the dns name?

Comment: You can't reference a loadbalancer as a  cloudformation resource unless it was created by Cloudformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reference a loadbalancer as a cloudformation resource unless it was created by Cloudformation.

You will need to recreate the loadbalancer via cloudformation in order to reference resource attributes like DNS Name.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the Arn you can use something like this

```
Fn::Join: [ "", [ "http://", !GetAtt <<LoadBalancerResourceName>>.DNSName ] ]
```

Comment: the point of this question is that the resource is not defined in the template

Answer (score 0):

```
LoadBalancerDNSName:
    Description: The DNS Name of the ALB
    Value: !GetAtt LoadBalancer.DNSName
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?